# Convert simple text with titles and subtiles into h2 and h3 respectively

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using an Open API to fetch list of titles or articles in my php/wordpress script. The format in which the API sends the response is like this :

```
Titles
1. The Versatile Vehicle: Driving with Style
2. Upgrade Your Ride: Discover the Thrills of Automobile Innovation
3. For Travellers and Adventurers: Exploring the Best in Automotive Design
4. Safety on the Road: Navigating with the Latest in Car Technology
5. The Lure of Luxury: Enjoying the Finest in Automotive Comfort

Subtitles
1. Expanding
```

So from the above response I want the Titles to be converted to h2 tags automatically and the Subtitles to h3. So it would be like this:

`<h2>The Versatile Vehicle: Driving with Style</h2>`

`<h3>Expanding</h3>`

So far I have tried this:

```
$ps = preg_split('#<p([^>])*>#',$txt);
```

This to convert p tags to array.

```
if (str_contains($ps[1], "Titles")) 
                    {
                        $titles = $ps[2];
                    }
```

This to check if string contains Titles than store that string in array after that seperated text using `<br>` tag.

```
$titles_array = preg_split('#<br([^>])*>#',$titles);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I am looking for a simple php or javascript solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that the response text is in the format specified in the question, with the titles and subtitles separated by `Titles` and `Subtitles` lines respectively, you can use another approach by splitting the string using `explode()` or `split()` in javascript by new line `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const str = 'Titles\n' +
  '1. The Versatile Vehicle: Driving with Style\n' +
  '2. Upgrade Your Ride: Discover the Thrills of Automobile Innovation\n' +
  '3. For Travellers and Adventurers: Exploring the Best in Automotive Design\n' +
  '4. Safety on the Road: Navigating with the Latest in Car Technology\n' +
  '5. The Lure of Luxury: Enjoying the Finest in Automotive Comfort\n' +
  '\n' +
  'Subtitles\n' +
  '1. Expanding';

let arr = str.split('\n');
let flagH2 = false;
let flagH3 = false;
let strResult = '';

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === 'Titles') {
    flagH2 = true;
  }
  if (arr[i] === 'Subtitles') {
    flagH3 = true;
    flagH2 = false;
  }
  if ((arr[i] !== 'Titles') && (arr[i] !== 'Subtitles') && arr[i].length !== 0) {
    arr[i] = arr[i].substring(3);
    if (flagH2) {
      strResult += '<h2>' + arr[i] + '</h2>\n';
    } else if (flagH3) {
      strResult += '<h3>' + arr[i] + '</h3>\n';
    }
  }
}
console.log(strResult);
```

Descriptive javascript, could be compacted but if you have to change something it's fully understandable

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with this code is you need to search for titles and subtitles in string like   if (arr[i].includes('Titles')) { else it is perfectly fine.

Comment: I understood you always have this kind of structure with title and subtitles. If you don't have those 2 words but only number lines, you would have to find when it is changing from titles to subtitles. If you have only numbers 1, 2, 3, 4... (for titles), followed by 1, 2, 3... (for subtitles), you can put a flag on "1". If you have 1 (titles), flag is on till next 1 (subtitles) where you put flag off.